# How to fork a GitHub angular module, modify it and republish it so I can use it?

Tags: angular, github, npm, module, fork

I've been trying to modify this module and to find a way to use it in my own project since yesterday without success : 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-carousel-3d

I'm developing an app with ionic and this module is what I'm looking for with some adjustment I need to make.

I tried to simply add the module folder once I cloned the project on my computer but I couldn't find a way to import and use it :

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-find-the-scss-of-a-node-module/126301

Now I'm trying to build my custom module from a fork of the original one as Sujan12 suggested but I just end up with a whole project and not the build version of it which prevents me from using it :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-carousel-3d-round

Does anyone have a well-explained documentation I could follow to do this ?
Also, I asked myself if forking and republishing a module from another person was ethically wrong ? Or is it how it should be done ?

Thanks !

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Comment: Thank you, I managed to do it with your link !